# ViewModel.setLookAtData() does not animate if using only bounds

Tags: here-api

I am attempting to zoom into a clicked shape or group of shapes. The actual move works, but the property to tell it to animate does not.

```
map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
   bounds: boundingBox
}, true);
```

This does move and zoom correctly but without animation. If I add a specific zoom level it animates as expected, but part of what I need it to figure out is the zoom level for me.

I can probably fake it if I can work out any reliable way to calculate what the zoom level should be manually, but that is less than ideal. For what ever reason, using only bounds breaks the feature that allows animation. Any work around for this?

Comment: it looks like an issue in the API. The team is aware of this and will deliver a fix in the near future.

Comment: @Tomas is there any update on this. Still seems to be broken with the latest version...

Comment: I'm sorry, this issue hasn't been fixed yet. I will ler you know once the fix is released.

Answer (score 0):

Map instance methods such as setZoom(), setCenter() and setViewBounds() accept a second argument indicating whether an animated transition should be applied.

We recommend not to create your own zoom animations as shown in the snippet below:

```
// Assumption: 'map' is initialized and available.
var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
var endZoom = currentZoom + 3;

// Update zoom level on each animation frame,
// till we reach endZoom:
function step() {
    currentZoom += 0.05;
    map.setZoom(currentZoom);

    (currentZoom < endZoom) && requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

// Start zoom animation
step();
```

Instead, call the method setZoom() with an optional second parameter to perform an animation:

> /**  * Assumption: 'map' is initialized and available  */ // Call
>   getZoom() with an optional second parameter, // indicating that an
>   animation is to be performed: map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 3, true);

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't address the issue.  Let me clarify...

I know my bounding area. I am using setLookAtData() to zoom to that area. This works, but the animate flag (which I have set to true in my example above) is not working. Unless I specify a zoom it does not animate. 

This is counter productive as I am using it to work out the zoom level for me. This appears to be a bug in the function that does not work in this specific scenario. I can't use setZoom as you described as I am missing the important value of what the endZoom would be.

Comment: can you please share the version of JS API ? is it 3.0 or 3.1? can you please also refer below example : https://developer.here.com/tutorials/javascript-api/

Comment: Yes. I am loading version 3.1 from this URL...
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js (as well as service, ui, mapevents and the css)

I have used that example you referenced. It works fine as I have only seen the bug when using only bounding box and NOT providing a zoom value explicitly. It moves to the desired zoom and position but doe NOT animate when calling this way.

Comment: Having the same issue. The following line of code does not animate:
`map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({ bounds: boundingBox }, true);`

Comment: Same bug.  ViewModel.setLookAtData(bound, animate);  Animate parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Workaround:  seems to work if you pass the bounds centroid:

```
let data = {bounds: bounds, position: bounds.getCenter() };
map.getViewModel().setLookAtData(data, opt_animate);
```